# Cannot suspend Dell Inspiron

Tags: 10.10, dell, suspend, inspiron

Since installing 10.10, my Dell Inspiron was able to suspend both when I closed the lid or chose to suspend from the menu.  At least it was until yesterday.  Now if I close the lid the computer freezes.  If I open the lid, the screen is black and will remain black until I force shut-down the computer.  Trying to suspend from the menu also does not work, the screen goes black and the system freezes.  A bit of googling brought up a bug that might be a possible cause?  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/522998

It says:  "When the XHCI module is loaded the system cannot suspend.

Manually unloading XHCI will allow suspend to complete normally.

If SUSPEND_MODULES="xhci" is added to /etc/pm/config.d/unload_module then the system can suspend normally.

Looking in /etc/pm/config.d/ I see an empty dir.  Does anyone know if this could be a solution, how to implement it if it is (make a new file unload_module and add the line in question?), and, if not, other ideas on where to go, or hardware tests to run?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to the bug report, the file doesn't exist so you have to create it in the first place.

Run the following commands in terminal:

If you run `gksudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/unload_modules`

And then add `SUSPEND_MODULES="xhci"`

Then save it, you will have to reboot in order to get the module suspended on boot.

See if that gives you your suspend functionality back.

However. It does look like the XHCI module is important and this work around may cause more bad than good.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I created the file, added the line, rebooted, but to no avail.  Same thing still happens: screen goes blank, computer freezes.  I might also note that hibernate does not work either, and that when I attempt either hibernation or suspension it seems like the cpu is fully loaded.  I cannot test to be sure, but the cpu fan turns on full speed and the laptop heats up the longer i leave it in this state.  Not sure if that makes any difference or not.

Comment: @Ben, from your description, it sounds like you are having the same problem that I am with my Lenovo Z360. I don't have the xhci or xhci-hcd modules loaded at all, so I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu the module is actulaly calld "xhci-hcd", and not "xhci".

You should change the file mentioned above.
Note that I have the same problem, and that fix worked for it... but for some reason its not working any more :(