# Dell Inspiron 8100 won't Suspend or Hibernate

Tags: 11.10, gnome, command-line

have a Dell Inspiron 8100 running Lubuntu 11.10 & doing it very well with one exception. Will not enter Suspend or Hibernate. Would really like it to suspend when the lid is closed.  When I close the lid it will not suspend & upon open it has a blank screen & requires a force shutdown.

First - I read the hardware most likely did not support suspend.

Then I found in the Hardware Compatibility section:
***I will you advise to change the driver in xorg.conf to the 3d acceleration driver from ati. There for change the Driver under Device to fglrx but first pleace install the ati-drivers from the restricted deb repository.***
Really have no idea how to do this - thought I would give option 3 a try first.

## 3) found this thread: [Cannot suspend Dell Inspiron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7552/...-dell-inspiron)

which might indicate running the following from Terminal:

***gksudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/unload_modules
And then add SUSPEND_MODULES="xhci-hcd"
save & reboot.***

Have tried various attempts with this command but the unload file is never there after, using the LS command.
Is there an ADD command I am supposed to be using?
What is meant by SAVE?  Ctl+O?  or should a I issue an actual SAVE command?  When I attempted to use the SAVE command it asked me to install it (did that) but afraid I really have no idea what I'm doing.
Am armed with a whole dictionary of Linux commands now but need some help getting started.  Perhaps if I could just get one thing to work it would be a jumping off point.  e.g. would like to see the "unload_modules" file there after performing the steps above.

thanks,
daemoncycler

Answer (score 1):

What you read in the Hardware Compatibility section was indicating that the driver for your graphics card won't let you suspend. I have the same thing; it stinks. Disable the ATI catalyst driver (you'll probably do this under Additional Drivers (aka Jockey)). You may notice significant decreases in graphics performance, but you will be able to suspend and/or hibernate successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience with my Dell inspiron and i followed these steps, it helped me solved the problem.

http://www.w7forums.com/wont-sleep-hibernate-t5577.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.